# How to turn off autocomplete for all input fields?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to set autocomplete to off `autocomplete="off"` on all html input fields? I'm using asp.net mvc (c#).

Answer (score -1):

If your input elements are in a form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I want to do this for all forms, without the need to put the `autocomplete="off"` into all of them. Only to add it in one place.